Using compileSdk 35 requires Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8.1.0 or higher: flutter error while building apk release file
[!] Using compileSdk 35 requires Android Gradle Plugin (AGP) 8.1.0 or higher.                                                         │ │  Please upgrade to a newer AGP version. The version of AGP that your project uses is likely defined in:                               │ │ /Users/tusharkhatri/Downloads/bmuptodown/android/settings.gradle,                                                                     │ │ in the 'plugins' closure.                                                                                                             │ │  Alternatively, if your project was created with an older version of the templates, it is likely                                      │ │ in the buildscript.dependencies closure of the top-level build.gradle:                                                                │ │ /Users/tusharkhatri/Downloads/bmuptodown/android/build.gradle.                                                                        │ │                                                                                                                                       │ │  Finally, if you have a strong reason to avoid upgrading AGP, you can temporarily lower the compileSdk version in the following file: │ │ /Users/tusharkhatri/Downloads/bmuptodown/android/app/build.gradle                                 
expected building apk release file

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78778617/android-resource-linking-failed-with-android-35-sdk-during-flutter-release-build

I just ran into the same problem when I upgrade flutter SDK and solve by changing gradle.setting inside /android/ and add those version changes:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

And It requires gradle version > 8.0 so change the gradle version inside /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties :
.....services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip


1st solution: delete android folder & recreate it on terminal with:
flutter create .

if u can't for any reason try this 2nd solution:
remove the code from the file gradle.setting inside /android
pluginManagement {
    def flutterSdkPath = {
        def properties = new Properties()
        file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
        def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
        assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
        return flutterSdkPath
    }()

    includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
    }
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "8.1.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.22" apply false
}

include ":app"

change the gradle version inside /android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties:
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-8.3-all.zip


I just ran into the same problem when I mistakenly switched to Flutter's master-branch instead of the stable-branch. I fixed it by going back to the stable-branch by running this from the command line: flutter channel stable.
It might not fix the underlying issue, but Flutter recommends using the stable-branch for production apps, so it might work for you as well unless you really have to run the master-branch.

Just go into your settings.gradle file : project/android/settings.gradle.
